# rubygems. rb (Load error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hi I was trying to install the devise gem, when I did the bundle install I got this error:

```
An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.1.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I search for the answer and I got this:

```
$ sudo rvm get stable
$ rvm list
$ sudo rvm --default use   
$ sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.1.2'
$ sudo bundle install
$ sudo rvm cleanup all
```

So I did, but now I think I made it worst, because when I try to do something with gems I get this error:

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

This is MAC OS 10.9.1

I would appreciate some help---thanks

Comment: please provide an output of `which ruby`, `which rvm`, `which gem`, and `ruby -v`

Comment: you should not be using `sudo` with `rvm`